# Where is config.php located in new ATK4-example install?

Tags: installation, atk4

I have just downloaded atk4-example and copied it to my Apache2 [webroot]
I can access the ATK welcome page at: htp://[server]/atk4-example/

I would like to set the DSN for MySQL in config.php, but I don't know where the file is

I can see /[webroot]/atk4-example/config-default.php
But there is no config.php

There is a /[webroot]/atk4-example/atk4/tools/sampleproject/config.php
But I assume this is unrelated sample code

The documentation mentions config.php, but I don't think it actually says where it is

Thanks for your help,

Greg

Comment: Not allowed answer my own question for 8 hours :-( Short answer is: copy config-default.php to config.php and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info on configuring Agile Toolkit: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/config

Comment: Yes thanks, I think that's what gave me the idea of copying default-config in situ. My problem was that it is never explained: where to place the config.php, if config-default.php is used, if config-distrib.php is used or if it's just an inactive template to be copied and renamed. The INSTALL file in atk4-example says to "edit" a non-existent config.php file

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed version 4.1.3 and had difficulty locating the correct config.php file to edit.

For the examples, you need to modify the config.php in the examples folder.